# How to access local definitions in Agda

Tags: agda, cubical-agda

I'm working in cubical agda. I am wondering how to access local definitions once outside of the local environment. For example, suppose I have the following code:

```hs
sucℤIso : ℤ ≅ ℤ
sucℤIso = iso sucℤ predℤ s r where
  s : section sucℤ predℤ
  s (pos zero) = refl
  s (pos (suc n)) = refl
  s (negsuc n) = refl

  r : retract sucℤ predℤ
  r (pos n) = refl
  r (negsuc zero) = refl
  r (negsuc (suc n)) = refl
```

Now, later on, I want to use `s` and apply it to something. Does anybody know how to do this?

Here are the details of how I am trying to use `s`:

I am trying to show `sucℤ (predℤ f(x)) = x` and I want to make the intermediate step of `f(x)=x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to local definitions if the [`where` block is declared as a module](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.1/language/let-and-where.html#where-blocks):

```
sucℤIso = iso sucℤ predℤ s r module Mod where
  s : section sucℤ predℤ
  s (pos zero) = refl
  s (pos (suc n)) = refl
  s (negsuc n) = refl

  r : retract sucℤ predℤ
  r (pos n) = refl
  r (negsuc zero) = refl
  r (negsuc (suc n)) = refl 

outer-s = Mod.s
outer-r = Mod.r
```

I often give the local `module` the same name as the function it's under. So we'd have `module sucℤIso where` here, and in the outer scope we can write:

```
outer-s = sucℤIso.s
outer-r = sucℤIso.r
```

Also note that a local `where` module is parameterized over all bound variables in local scope, and the local definitions are lifted out as functions. For example:

```
open import Data.Bool

f : Bool -> Bool
f x = y module f where
  y = true

f' : Bool -> Bool
f' = f.y
```

Here `f.y` is lifted out as a function with `Bool -> Bool` type.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge this isn't possible, but you have a couple of options:

1. Declare `s` and `r` outside of `sucℤIso`. The `where` blocks are specifically local definitions: if you don't intend to only use it locally, don't declare it to be local.
2. For your specific case, you can use `Iso.fun` and `Iso.inv` to recover `s` and `r` from the isomorphism. `Iso` is just a record type, and `iso` is just a constructor (see [here](https://agda.github.io/cubical/Cubical.Foundations.Isomorphism.html#840)), so you can use the field projections `fun` and `inv` to recover the fields. So `Iso.fun sucℤIso` should yield `s` and `Iso.inv sucℤIso` should yield `r`.

   Note that this has nothing to do with the `where` clause, it's just because `Iso` is a record that you can project fields out of. If, for example, you just passed `s` and `r` to some function, there wouldn't always be a way to get them back.

Comment: I see, thank you!